# Installing Win10 SDK (any version) hangs every time

Tags: visual-studio, sdk, windows-10

I'm trying to install the Win10 SDK (any version - logs below are from 17763) for use in Visual Studio 2019. Every time I try, the install hangs. I finally have to go into Task Manager and kill off several processes. There are usually three for `winsdksetup.exe` and one `Windows Installer`.

I've tried installing from the Visual Studio Installer, and also from the standalone SDK installer. They all hang, even the full ISO download of the SDK. Installing it standalone (outside Visual Studio), it gets as far as "Updating Settings" (around 45%) and then just sits there. I've left it for hours. I go in and find the same dead processes.

The logs, of course, are massive. A few relevant bits I've found are messages such as:

```
MSI (s) (84:D8) [11:40:21:462]: Warning: Local cached package 'C:\Windows\Installer\75742b.msi' is missing.
MSI (s) (84:D8) [11:40:21:463]: SOURCEMGMT: Source is invalid due to missing/inaccessible package.
MSI (s) (84:58) [11:43:33:684]: Product: Kits Configuration Installer -- Error 1714. The older version of Kits Configuration Installer cannot be removed.  Contact your technical support group.  System Error 1612.
```

It seems like something is missing or broken in my system... does anyone know what it could be, or how to fix this?

Comment: 1612 = ERROR_INSTALL_SOURCE_ABSENT. Old SDK can't be removed, because MSI file was not found in cache

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. Windows SDK installation just stuck at 35% with "Updating Settings" message and it not moving a bit.

Looking through log files "%tmp%\standalonesdk", I noticed that error in log appeared just like above question.

I was able to fix it by forcing "Kits Configuration Installer" to uninstall, using tools provided by Microsoft here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/windows-fix-problems-that-block-programs-being-installed-or-removed.

Comment: Life saver. Thanks!

Comment: Extreme caution advised. I had the exact same problem as question poster but trying this answer sent my machine into a bluescreen-crash-restart loop for a long while. It didn't even fix the problem when the computer finally recovered. I'm not going to downvote since it worked for someone, but I advise caution!